# Remove random spaces in from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, data-cleaning

After using pdftotext on a my file there is a field that has spaces between character; the field that has the value for a persons name.

Most records are fine, and it appears that usually the last name has this issue; although names are not formatted the same way. When this issue occurs it usually uses uppercase letter.

what is the best preg_match or regex solution to cleaning these names? Its possible being off by a letter is acceptable (for example, if the middle initial is appended to the last name; is it even possible to prevent this programmatically?)

Example of the returned values:

```
R U S S E L L , Robert T 
Samuel D E N N I E S
Timmy O ' B R I E N
```

Comment: Is there only a middle initial when it has the last name followed by a comma?

Comment: So far, that is correct. I don't have an extensive record, so it may include a full middle name at some point. Unfortunately this is the only information I have from just a handful of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but you can try this:

```
$str = preg_replace("~[A-Z']\K ~", '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

For capital letters followed by space or end of line, find this:

```
([A-Z])( |$)
```

...and replace with:

```
$1
```

...which should produce:

```
RUSSELL, Robert T
Samuel DENNIES
Timmy O' BRIEN
```